# Combining date and time using moment causing deprecation warning

Tags: node.js, momentjs

In my nodejs application, I have user-based input for starting date and starting time for achieving some task. I need to combine start date and start time input by the user and insert it into one DateTime object format as: `2020-05-29T10:43:39.278Z`. Here is the code:

```
function(start_time, start_date){
    const time = moment(start_time).format('LT');
    console.log('show timing', time); // gives, 4:12 PM

    const d = moment(start_date).format('L'); 
    console.log('new date', d); //gives, 05/29/2020

    const final_start_date = moment(d +' '+ time).format();
    console.log('final_start_date', final_start_date)
  }
```

But `console.log('final_start_date', final_start_date)` throws an error as :

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments:
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 05/29/2020 4:12 PM, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
```

The arguments `start_time` and `start_date` are stored in MongoDB as ISO format with a Date type. 
I am unable to understand where things are getting wrong, kindly help to resolve the issue.

------------------UPDATION------------------

```
 const START_TIME = moment(start_time, "hh:mm:ss").format("LT"),
    END_TIME = moment(end_time, "hh:mm:ss").format("LT");

  const START_DATE = moment(start_date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("L"),
    END_DATE = moment(end_date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("L");


    console.log("START-TIME: ", START_TIME);
    console.log("END-TIME: ", END_TIME)

    console.log("START-DATE: ", START_DATE);
    console.log("END-DATE: ", END_DATE)


  const START_AT = moment(START_DATE + " " + START_TIME, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").format(),
    END_AT = moment(END_DATE + " " + END_TIME, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").format();


    console.log("START-AT: ", START_AT);
    console.log("END-AT: ", END_AT)
```

console.logs()

```
START-TIME:  8:29 PM
END-TIME:  8:30 PM
START-DATE:  05/29/2020
END-DATE:  05/29/2020
START-AT:  Invalid date
END-AT:  Invalid date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format when passing a string to moment (without a format string), we can do this by formatting the time and date to this format separately, then concatenating.

```js
function createFinalStartDate(start_time, start_date){
    const time = moment(start_time).format('HH:mm:ss');
    console.log('Time component:', time);
    const d = moment(start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
    console.log('Date component:', d);
    let isoTimestamp = `${d}T${time}`;
    console.log("ISO 8601 timestamp:", isoTimestamp);
    const final_start_date = moment(isoTimestamp).format();
    console.log('final_start_date', final_start_date)
}

function test() {
    let start_time = new Date();
    let start_date = new Date();
    createFinalStartDate(start_time, start_date);
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Agreed. But if date format is not in ISO then user can specify format string as I answered. It need not to be an ISO each time.

Comment: You can certainly do it either way, use an unambiguous format such as ISO 8601 / unix, or use a known format such "HH:mm". We do want to be wary of using "LT" or "L", as format string since the result of format() in this case will vary by the machine locale. For example, in the US this would result in something like 3:15 PM while in Germany this might result in 15:15.

Comment: But the date and time stored in the mongoose database are already in ISO format. "duration" : {
        "startDate" : ISODate("2020-05-29T10:41:39.278Z"),
        "endDate" : ISODate("2020-05-29T10:41:39.278Z")
    },
    "timing" : {
        "from" : ISODate("2020-05-29T10:42:39.278Z"),
        "to" : ISODate("2020-05-29T10:43:39.278Z")
    },

Comment: but moment(d +' '+ time) is not an ISO format. The warning is coming for it.

Comment: Ohkay. Understood

Answer (score 1):

moment() takes 2 parameters

1. Date String
2. Format

You need to pass second parameter so that it will correctly convert your date.

Just added format for each moment constructor and deprecation warning went away.

Modified your code as:

```
    var fn = function(start_time, start_date){
    const time = moment(start_time, "h:mm a").format('LT');
    console.log('show timing', time); // gives, 4:12 PM

    const d = moment(start_date, "MM/DD/YYYY").format('L'); 
    console.log('new date', d); //gives, 05/29/2020

    const final_start_date = moment(d +' '+ time, "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a").format();
    console.log('final_start_date', final_start_date)
  }

  fn("4:12 PM", "05/29/2020");
```

> Note: You don't need second parameter if you pass date string in ISO
>   format like this moment("2020-05-29T16:55:35+05:30").format()

Comment: in ` const time = moment(start_time, "h:mm a").format('LT');`, what does 'a' after hh:mm stands for?

Comment: a stands for AM  /  PM

Comment: Is there any way that it can identify the AM or PM automatically from the time value received from the user, without having me to pass explicitly?

Comment: One more question, If I input '2020-05-29T10:42:39.278Z' like  fn("2020-05-29T10:42:39.278Z"), it will still work the same right?

Comment: Current function is taking 2 parameters date and time separately. You need to update accordingly. For date format like 2020-05-29T10:42:39.278Z you don't have to specify format string because it an ISO format. just use moment(2020-05-29T10:42:39.278Z) moment will automatically recognize it

Comment: Yes just for example sake I wrote only one parameter, but eventually, I'll be passing two parameters. Thanks for clarification btw :)

Comment: It is not giving proper time as required. `console.log('final_start_date', final_start_date)` is invalid

Comment: const START_AT = moment(START_DATE + " " + START_TIME, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss").format() here  format should be "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss". MM should be first

Comment: still invalid. Even the start-end date and time is also wrong. :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214910/discussion-between-bubble-cord-and-shivaji-mutkule).

Answer (score 0):

moment.js

`moment(start_time).format('HH:mm:ss').toString()`;